# Regex find word NOT starting with " or ' AND ends with space

Tags: regex, regex-negation

i've been trying to create a regex to find words that do not start with " or ' and ends with space.

This is what i have so far :

`\b(?![i|"|'])test.([^\s,]+)`

Test data

```
SHOULD WORK -> test.something test.somethingelse.another  // 2 Matches This is correct

SHOULD NOT WORK ->  one.test.two  // 1 mathces should be 0 is not the start of word

SHOULD NOT WORK -> "test.shouldnotbeselected 'test.something  //2 matches should be 0 has ' or "

NEGATIVE LOOK AHEAD WORKS WITH "i" and not with quoutes    I don't know why  -> 
itest.doesnottake  'test.doesnottake "test.doesnottake // 2Matches should be 0
```

[image: Regex 101 screenshot]

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you it works ! Been at it for 3 hours :)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<!\S)test\.(\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t0DBvY/1). *Details*:

- `(?<!\S)` - a left-hand whitespace boundary
- `test\.` - `test.` string
- `(\S+)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more whitespace chars, as many as possible.